# i want to install packages

Tags: npm, proxy, hadoop-yarn

Every time I run `npm` or yarn I got this error:

```
yarn add v1.22.4
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.1.1:8080".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\New folder\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command
```

I've tried to change port settings:

`yarn` config set proxy http://192.168.1.1:8080

`yarn` config set https-proxy http://192.168.1.1:8080

or to turn it off:

`yarn` config set no-proxy true

To restart the PC and still the same error!!